# Copy html of an element in a variable and delete some elements in the new variable using Jquery

Tags: jquery, clone, removechild

I'm trying to copy the current HTML of a page in a variable and then delete some elements for convert the content of the variable in a pdf. I'm trying like this.

```
var html= $("body");
 var html2=html.clone();
 var btn=html2.find("#cmd");
 html2.remove(btn);
 html2.html();
```

But is not working because deletes everithing in the current DOM.

Comment: `var html2 = $(html.prop('outerHTML'));` <= will get the html version of the body, and then will convert all that html to dom elements, so it is entirely disconnected from the original.

Answer (score 0):

remove btn object & re-assign html content in original html object.

```
var html= $("body");
var html2=html.clone();
var btn=html2.find("#cmd");
btn.remove();
html.html(html2);
```